# Which method of sending messages in TCP more preferred?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I'm playing around making a TCP client/server application using C# and I am confused on what's better to use between these two style in sending messages through the network.

The first style I encountered is converting the message to a byte array and writing it to the NetworkStream of an instance of a TcpClient using `NetworkStream.Write(*)` method.

```
void StyleOne(string msg)
{
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
            nwStream.Flush();
            client.Close();
}
```

Another style I encountered is passing the NetworkStream of the TcpClient instance to a StreamWriter and then using the `StreamWriter.Write()` method to write the message to the stream

```
void StyleTwo(string msg)
{
            TcpClient client = New TcpClient(ip, port);
            StreamWriter writer = New StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            writer.Write(msg);
            writer.Flush();
            client.Close();
}
```

Which of these two is more efficient in terms of **Memory, Speed, and Performance** if messages that will be sent through the network would at most a megabyte large?

Comment: first method is better because you know the encoding.  Ascii encoding will remove non-printable characters.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @jdweng - Ascii _contains_ non printable characters, and they can  (and must) be transmittable over TCP.

Comment: This is not ASCII.  It is binary an using encoding on binary data will corrupt the data.  Must be send a byte array or packed (like a 64 bit string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `StreamWriter` instance always uses the same encoding (which you can specify in its constructor), and has some convenience methods to write different types of data to the stream.

In your first example, you more or less do exactly what a `StreamWriter` would do under the hood: apply the encoding and write data to the underlying stream.

If you have to send multiple bits of data (in the same encoding), using the `StreamWriter` would result in alot cleaner code. For just a single `string` I don't think it really matters which approach you take.

Comment: So basically, they are just the same in terms of what they do and efficiency? If I create an instance of the `StreamWriter` using this

`StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), ASCIIEncoding.ASCII)`

It will be just the same as the first code snippet? No difference in memory, speed, etc?

Comment: @ReiSchneider There's always a difference, applying the encoding yourself has a tiny bit less overhead. I do think L.B _is_ trying to help though, because so many people tend to optimize for performance not realizing their code is becoming a big mess. Just don't take it personally if that's not the case here :)